# Confusion in analogy Hailstorm : Destruction :: Brainstorm :?

Tags: analogy

I am solving some problems in an analogy. At one point I have got the following analogy.

### Hailstorm : Destruction :: Brainstorm : ?

a ) Construction b ) Innovation c) Neuroticism d) Disorientation

According to me, Brainstorm is the reason for Innovation. But a book says the answer will be disorientation.

Can you please enlighten me the correct answer?

Comment: A hailstorm brings destruction and a [brainstorm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorm) brings...

Comment: Brainstorm has two meanings. As well as the recently-invented innovation technique it has a much older meaning of "a moment in which one is suddenly unable to think clearly or act sensibly."

Comment: If the book says the answer is *disorientation*, then that *is* the correct answer (per the book). Are you asking why the book would claim that? (Because of one of the senses of the word [*brainstorm*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorm).) Or do you think that the book is wrong for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your textbook is using the secondary definition of brainstorm. This may be due to an older textbook.

> Brainstorm
>   noun
>   1. a spontaneous group discussion to produce ideas and ways of solving problems.
>
> 2. INFORMAL, a moment in which one is suddenly unable to think clearly or act sensibly.

This second definition provides a direct analogy to disorientation. Through the following relationship:

> Hailstorm- a storm of heavy hail : Destruction- the action or process of causing so much damage to something that it no longer exists or cannot be repaired. Brainstorm- a moment in which one is suddenly unable to think clearly or act sensibly.: Disorientation- a state of mental confusion. This provides more analogical value than to Innovation- making changes in something established, especially by introducing new methods, ideas, or products

Comment: That means, the answer will be  innovation ?

Comment: Hailstorm- a storm of heavy hail  : Destruction- the action or process of causing so much damage to something that it no longer exists or cannot be repaired.
Brainstorm- a moment in which one is suddenly unable to think clearly or act sensibly.: Disorientation- a state of mental confusion.

This provides more analogical value than to Innovation- making changes in something established, especially by introducing new methods, ideas, or products

Comment: Please cite your references properly.